# как сохранить введенные пользователем данные в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Всем привет. В базу данных SQLite я добавляю "Сотрудника" при добавлении сотрудника  в базу данных пользователь должен заполнить поля которые относятся к сотруднику, например имя, фамилия зарплата и.т.д.
У сотрудника есть несколько атрибутов таких как "skill" и "department" этих атрибутов сотрудник может иметь несколько, по этому когда юзер заполняет все поля с атрибутами ему предлагается добавить еще поле например поле "skill" чтоб добавить еще "skill", таких поле "skill" можно добавлять сколько хочешь и я реализовал это с помощью RecyclerView. Но проблема заключается в следующем - когда пользователь хочет добавить еще поле "skill", появляется пустой EditText и юзер  заполняет это поле  данными, а вот как сохранить эту строку я не знаю, ведь при нажатии add skill в адаптер передается пустая строка затем юзер заполняет эту строку , а вот как сохранить эту строку в список который содержит адаптер я не могу разобраться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот это класс адаптер

```
public class AdapterAddSkill extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAddSkill.MyViewHolderAddEmployee> {
    private ArrayList<String> skillsList;
    private Context context;

    public AdapterAddSkill(ArrayList<String> skillsList, Context context) {
        this.skillsList = skillsList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolderAddEmployee onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_skill, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolderAddEmployee(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolderAddEmployee holder, final int position) {
        holder.closeCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                skillsList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return skillsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    public static class MyViewHolderAddEmployee extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageButton closeCard;
        private EditText skillEditText;

        public MyViewHolderAddEmployee(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            closeCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteSkillCard);
            skillEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.skillText);
        }
    }

}
```

Вот это активити в которой юзер заполняет данные о сотруднике и добавляет его в базу данных

```
public class AddEmploy extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText nameEditText, lastNameEditText, employeeIdEditText,
            salaryEditText, departmentEditText, skillEditText;
    private ArrayList<String> skillsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> departmentsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private AdapterAddSkill adapterAddSkill;
    private RecyclerView skillRecyclerView;
    private AdapterAddDepartment adapterAddDepartment;
    private RecyclerView departmentRecyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_employ);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        nameEditText = findViewById(R.id.name);
        lastNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        employeeIdEditText = findViewById(R.id.employeeId);
        salaryEditText = findViewById(R.id.salary);
        departmentEditText = findViewById(R.id.department);
        skillEditText = findViewById(R.id.skill);
        skillRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_skill);
        departmentRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_department);
        adapterAddSkill = new AdapterAddSkill(skillsList, this);
        adapterAddDepartment = new AdapterAddDepartment(departmentsList, this);
        skillRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        departmentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        skillRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterAddSkill);
        departmentRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterAddDepartment);

    }

    public void onClickBtn(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.addDepartmentText:
                departmentsList.add("");
                adapterAddDepartment.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case R.id.addSkillText:
                skillsList.add("");
                adapterAddSkill.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case R.id.saveEmployee_info:
                addEmployToDatabase();
                addDepartmentToDatabase();
                addSkillToDatabase();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void addEmployToDatabase() {
        String employeeId = employeeIdEditText.getText().toString();
        String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
        String lastName = lastNameEditText.getText().toString();
        String salary = salaryEditText.getText().toString();
        MyQuery.addEmployee(new Employ(employeeId, name, lastName, salary));
    }

    private void addSkillToDatabase() {
        String employeeId = employeeIdEditText.getText().toString();
        String skill = skillEditText.getText().toString();
        MyQuery.addSkill(new Skill(employeeId, skill));
        for (int i = 0; i < skillsList.size(); i++) {
            MyQuery.addSkill(new Skill(employeeIdEditText.getText().toString()
                    , skillsList.get(i)));
        }
    }

    private void addDepartmentToDatabase() {
        String department = departmentEditText.getText().toString();
        String employeeId = employeeIdEditText.getText().toString();
        MyQuery.addDepartment(new Department(employeeId, department));
        for (int i = 0; i < departmentsList.size(); i++) {
            MyQuery.addDepartment(new Department(employeeIdEditText.getText().toString(),
                    departmentsList.get(i)));
        }
    }

    private void showAllEmployees() {
        List<Employ> employs = MyQuery.getAllEmployees();
        for (int i = 0; i < employs.size(); i++) {
            Log.i(".......Employees", employs.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

    private void showAllSkills() {
        List<Skill> skills = MyQuery.getAllSkills();
        for (int i = 0; i < skills.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("......Skills", skills.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

    private void showAllDepartments() {
        List<Department> departments = MyQuery.getAllDepartments();
        for (int i = 0; i < departments.size(); i++) {
            Log.i(".........Departments", departments.get(i).toString());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: TextWatcher на EditText и отслеживать событие завершения ввода?

Comment: я думал об этом, но мне не нравиться TextWatcher тем что он будет вызываться каждый раз  при каждом ввденном символе

Comment: А как вы хотите, чтобы он не каждый раз вызывался? Сделайте таймер, например, после каждого нажатия сбрасывайте и по новой, а когда пользователь прекратил ввод прошло к примеру 3 секунды, сработал `TextWatcher`. Но это тоже будет работать постоянно и интервалить, не понимаю ваше не довольство.

Comment: Ещё, возможно, Вам стоит сделать редактирование профиля более атомарным и сохранять в БД уже после добавления всех необходимых данных. Хотя я в код не вникал, так что это просто предположение

Comment: А если получать список скилов во время нажатия на Save из адаптера и сохранять всё вместе?

Comment: JackFromBB, БД содержит три таблицы: 1) Employee.  2)Skills.  3) Departments 
Моя цель это при нажатии Save  все введенные данные должны записаться в соответствующую им таблицу. Но проблема в том что я не могу разобраться как получить список скилов из адаптера, то есть не могу разобраться как сохранять данные введенные пользователем в строку "skill" в список

Comment: @Artem , можно попробовать в адаптере сделать поле List<String> и хранить в нем массив добавленных EditText'ов и добавить getScils(), что бы получать значения полей циклом в Save. Думаю есть более изящные способы, но это пришло в голову первым)

Comment: Блин, не List<String>, а List<EditText> конечно)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AdapterAddSkill extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAddSkill.MyViewHolderAddEmployee> {
private ArrayList<String> skillsList;

public AdapterAddSkill(ArrayList<String> skillsList) {
    this.skillsList = skillsList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolderAddEmployee onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_skill, parent, false);
    MyViewHolderAddEmployee vh = new MyViewHolderAddEmployee(view, new MyCustomEditTextListener());
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolderAddEmployee holder, final int position) {
    holder.myCustomEditTextListener.updatePosition(position);
    holder.skillEditText.setText(skillsList.get(position));

    holder.closeCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            skillsList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return skillsList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}



public static class MyViewHolderAddEmployee extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   private ImageButton closeCard;
   private EditText skillEditText;
   private MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener;


    public MyViewHolderAddEmployee(@NonNull View itemView, MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener) {
        super(itemView);
        closeCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteSkillCard);
        skillEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.skillText);
        skillEditText.addTextChangedListener(myCustomEditTextListener);
        this.myCustomEditTextListener = myCustomEditTextListener;
    }


}

private class MyCustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher {
    private int position;

    public void updatePosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        skillsList.set(position, s.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Нашел вот такое решение, работает оьлично